# VSC - is it possible to read snippets from multiple files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

- if there is a file called javascript.json --> then every .js file reads its content when u using VSC.
- I would like to not only read snippets from javascript.json but from javascript2.json as well when editing a js file in vsc. (or any other random name, the main thing is to read snippets for javascript from multiple json files)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have additional snippet files in your workspace `.vscode` directory.

The file has the extension: `.code-snippets`

You can limit the language for a snippet by using the `scope` attribute.

```
{
    // Place your test workspace snippets here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a scope, prefix, body and 
    // description. Add comma separated ids of the languages where the snippet is applicable in the scope field. If scope 
    // is left empty or omitted, the snippet gets applied to all languages. The prefix is what is 
    // used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are: 
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. 
    // Placeholders with the same ids are connected.
  "Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
      "console.log('$1');",
      "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
}
```